# Data structure to answer queries

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Need some help in coming up with a data structure for answering this question. The objective is to perform Q queries of the following type on an array:

1. Type 1: Given L and R, return [image: \sum_{j = L to R} \sum_{k = j + 1 to R} (A_j * A_k)]
2. Type 2: Update position idx with a value val

How to answer these queries efficiently? The naive way is n^2. I was thinking along the lines of maintaining cumulative sum, since A_j factors out of the summation in the above equation.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) is what you are looking for.

> A Fenwick tree or binary indexed tree is a data structure that can
> efficiently update elements and calculate prefix sums in a table of
> numbers.

Comment: Is this interpretation correct: We will have a Fenwick tree or a Segment tree to answer the sum queries and then for a given query we compute A[i] * (sum of A[i + 1] to A[n]) + A[i + 1] * (sum of A[i + 2] to A[n]) and so on. This will make each query O(n).

Comment: Each query will take O(logn). I recommend [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDV1Zeh2NRsB6SWUrDFW2RmDotAfPbeHu) for better understanding of Fenwick trees.

Comment: Thanks, will check the link.

Answer (score 1):

`Segment Tree`, `Fenwick Tree`, and `Square Root Decomposition` are useful data structures to solve this kind of problem in better time complexity. (faster than n^2).